# How to count the number of times a regex captures a group ?

Tags: java, regex, grouping

I have the regex `([A-Za-z]+)`

My example text is:

```
jerk jerk jerk jerk jerk jerk jerk jerk jerk jerk
```

I'm trying to find out how many times a group is captured in an example. I want the answer for the example input to be 10.

How would I go implementing this?

Comment: Seems like the above should get 10, not 9. Am I missing something?

Comment: I counted wrong but, when I ran the code the result was 20 instead of 10. Should I just divide the answer by 2?

Comment: @Ben Waters - No you should not.  That is voodoo programming!!  Show us the actual code ...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Do you simply want to count the number of spaces in the text (which is 9)?

Comment: I got it to work. I was used to using the * to not throw an exception, taking it off made it work

Comment: You mean you were using `([A-Za-z]*)`?  Yes, that would match 20 times: "jerk" 10 times, alternating with 10 empty strings.  You might want to post that comment as an answer and accept it, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify what you want to match in the regex. What you have will match any alphabetic character. Here you go:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException //throws exceptions
    {
        String str = "jerk jerk jerk jerk\njerk jerk jerk\njerk jerk\njerk";
        String regex = "jerk";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        int count = 0;
        while(m.find())
            count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we can presume that the exact work value is not known nor exactly repeating. Course, I know what happens when we assume.

Comment: My point was that though the example given was the trivial case of all "jerk", the fact that a "wildcard" was used suggests that the actual data probably varies and may not be know at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
    count++;
```

Comment: Might be that your regex is not specific enough or that the quantifier is not being greedy. Try `([A-Za-z]+(?:\s+|$)` ie. make it grab all the way to the whitespace.

Comment: You might get some insight if you did `System.out.print(matcher.group(0));`